# Crear expresion que devuelva el año actual en un report rdlc de winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, rdlc

He probado muchas combinaciones, pero ninguna da resultado.
Me devuelven error, o la fecha entera, o la fecha con la hora, y me interesa solo la parte del año actual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A alguien se le ocurre la posible solución?
Quiero el año actual para no tener que modificar el programa cada año añadiendo una triste string ^^'

El resultado final que quiero vendria a ser asi:
Número: (Año) / id de un presupuesto
Ejemplo: Número: 2020/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En rdlc tenés que utilizar dos funciones **Year()** y **Now()**, te quedaría así:

```
=Year(Now())
```

Saludos.

Comment: La expresión que dices si funciona, pero da error a la hora de concatenar otras cosas, he editado la pregunta inicial para mostrar lo que quiero conseguir, a ver si me puedes ayudar con eso ^^

Las concatenaciones que tengo y dan error son estas:
="Número: "+ Year(Now())+ "/"+First(Fields!id.Value, "Presupuesto")

Comment: ="Número: " & Year(Now()) & "/" & First(Fields!id.Value, "Presupuesto")

Comment: Probá así, sino decime que error te da

Comment: Perfecto, ya funciona. Es curioso que en todas las expresiones que he usado el + para concatenar no ha dado ningun error y aquí si ^^'
Gracias!